# Moving matches to produce largest possible number

Tags: matches

María Lucía Uribe´s recent match-moving puzzle ([Move matches and make largest possible number](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100739/move-matches-and-make-largest-possible-number)) begs for the following matter to be settled once and for all.

If each of the numbers from 100 to 999 is written using matches, such as 907 below, and I am allowed to move three of any number´s matches, with which number can I come up with the largest resulting possible number?

Below are admissible shapes for seven ramaining digits.

[image] [image]

Comment: Does 1 have to have 2 matchsticks, or can it have just 1?

Comment: @bobble Two matches

Comment: I think you need to specify in the puzzle what shapes are allowed for each digit.

Comment: @msh210 Done! Good idea!

Comment: Althought it is not really a number by lateral thinking many numbers (like 91) can be turned into rot 13 (Vasvavgl) by moving three or four matches @BernardoRecamánSantos

Comment: Does, for example, removing the horizontal pieces from an 8 count as creating 11, or two 1's? Or is this considered an illegal move as these both share the same character space? Ie, should "legal" 1's be in separate grids?

Comment: @Daniel Allowed, perfectly legal!

Answer (score 6):

Ok, let's get the ball rolling:

Moving three matches

> [image]

Moving four (not actually asked here but in the referenced Q)

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I was thinking

> 990 --> 7^997 
>  [image]

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not drawing matches, only numbers:

> Starting with the three digit number 444, then moving three matches, I get the six digit number 111111